# What's the highest level of official recognition that an African country gave to their "brothers" in the US?

Tags: united-states, international-relations, soviet-union, africa

I'm guessing that some African countries might have given their "brothers" (see further below a discussion what this could possibly mean) over the Atlantic, meaning African Americans, some kind of symbolic nation-like recognition. Alas, the only examples I could find on Wikipedia supporting outright self-determination are Communist/Soviet movements that [tried to encourage "Black Belt" independence in the US](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/African-American_self-determination#During_the_USSR).

Some African countries at least partially fell under the Soviet sphere of influence at times, so that provides a possible link to investigate. From that Wikipedia page it's not clear when the Soviets themselves abandoned such a line [it only says when CPUSA did it, but there were splinter groups not giving it up]; the Soviets themselves might have abandoned it during WWII, but I don't really know.

In any case, independently of Soviet influence, there might have been some kind of African nativist movements supporting the idea (and gaining power in an African country); again I don't know if anything like that existed... hence my question.

And regarding the meaning of "brothers"; if Wikipedia is correct, [pan-Africanism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pan-Africanism) seems to cover that

> Pan-Africanism is a worldwide intellectual movement that aims to encourage and strengthen bonds of solidarity between all people of African descent. Based on a common fate going back to the Atlantic slave trade, the movement extends beyond continental Africans, with a substantial support base among the African diaspora in the Caribbean, Latin America and the United States. It is based on the belief that unity is vital to economic, social, and political progress and aims to "unify and uplift" people of African descent. **The ideology asserts that the fate of all African peoples and countries are intertwined. At its core Pan-Africanism is "a belief that African peoples, both on the continent *and in the diaspora*, share not merely a common history, but a common destiny".**

But I don't intend this question to be narrowly focused on self-labeled "pan-Africans" if other movements were similar enough but called themselves something else.

So **what are some examples of official or semi-official recognition given by an African country to a US-based entity claiming to represent at least a semi-independent US "[Black nation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_nationalism)"?** (again, I'm leaving pretty open which US movement this refers to).

I'm not sure why this question gets downvoted with no stated objections, so let me make more clear what kind of examples I'm looking for: say group X declared some kind of virtual nation for African-Americans and then African country Y drums up X's existence in speeches, or even sends some kind of unofficial ambassador(s) to X, or there are other mutual friendship visits by the leaderships of X and Y (not necessarily at the very top) etc.

Comment: What's the objection to this question?

Comment: No objection here, but please clarify the *"Brothers"* part -- are nations brothers by virtue of existing on the same *"Parent"* continent?  Europe, Asia, *et al* are seldom considered parents of constituent national siblings.

Comment: @agc: I'm not sure how to frame that any better than by a vague term like that. Clearly nations claiming ethnic connections with "brothers" are rather common, e.g. Yugoslavia has plenty of examples with enclaves etc. Or even "pan-Slavism" where the connection is less obvious. Since I don't know what ideology might be at work here, maybe a very broad notion of "pan-Africanism", but I'm reluctant to appropriate a term that has another meaning. Actually after looking at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pan-Africanism it might not be too wrong, let me read more on that.

Comment: "people of African descent in the Americas" could be substituted for "brothers".

Comment: @guest271314: I think that would make the title too long.

Comment: @Fizz Possibly, but would move towards a correct analysis of the culture that you are asking about. Also note that the African culture is not predominantly patriarchal. Women have a status and standing in African culture equal to if not greater than men; historically at times even in warfare. "brothers" excludes the "sisters" https://history.stackexchange.com/a/46789/28734. From the perspective of a great deal of Africans, if there is, or they believe in a "god", "god" is the black woman; i.e.g., Isis (not the group who the U.S. named and funded to deface the deity of Ancient Egypt in Africa)

Comment: @Fizz The question is significant and raises important points. By now it should be clear to you that the demographic at Politics SE is, if not entirely, substantially devoid of African perspectives - who are not trying to "pass" as not being African perspectives. Am just pointing out the lack of cultural awareness, understanding evident at the title, language within the question. You can perhaps only imagine how an individual of African descent views questions; answers about "blacks"; "close" votes here. Angela Davis, Assata Shakur; the sisters are as strident if not more than the "brothers".

Comment: @Fizz Absolutely no idea what's the problem. Upvoted.

Comment: I feel this question is just too vague to be answerable but the relationship between [Algeria and the Black Panthers](https://africasacountry.com/2018/07/algeria-and-the-american-black-panther-party) seems relevant.

Answer (score 5):

There are several examples, two of which involve Libya and not necessarily based on being "brothers" alone, but rather relating to religion, or Islam

- [Nation of Islam Tries to Accept Gift of $1 Billion from Libya](https://www.wsj.com/articles/SB841007141275125500)
- [When the FBI set up a Chicago street gang to have them be tried as a terrorist organization](https://africasacountry.com/2014/03/whitehistorymonth-when-the-fbi-set-up-a-chicago-street-gang-to-be-tried-as-a-terrorist-organization)

On the international stage, according to the U.N., the world is currently within the ***International Decade for People of African Descent***

> In proclaiming this Decade, the international community is recognizing
>   that **people of African descent represent a distinct group** whose human
>   rights must be promoted and protected. Around 200 million people
>   identifying themselves as being of African descent live in the
>   Americas. Many millions more live in other parts of the world, outside
>   of the African continent. (emphasis added)

Further [UN panel says the U.S. owes reparations to African-Americans](https://www.pbs.org/newshour/nation/reparations-african-americans-un)

> The United States owes African-Americans reparations for slavery, a
>   [recent report](https://daccess-ods.un.org/TMP/3234558.99953842.html) by a United Nations-affiliated group said.
>
> The UN Working Group of Experts on People of African Descent said that
>   compensation is necessary to combat the disadvantages caused by [245
>   years](http://www.pbs.org/wnet/slavery/teachers/lesson1c.html) of legally allowing the sale of people based on the color of
>   their skin.
>
> The U.N. group warned that the U.S. has not confronted its legacy of
>   “racial terrorism.”
>
> The report, which is non-binding, specified that reparations can come
>   in a variety of ways, including educational opportunities,
>   psychological rehabilitation, debt cancellation and formal apologies.
>
> Some institutions have [started to take these steps](http://www.pbs.org/newshour/bb/georgetown-university-tries-make-amends-profiting-slavery/). Georgetown
>   University announced earlier this month it would offering free tuition
>   for descendants of the 272 slaves that were sold in 1838 to help pay
>   the university’s debts.
>
> The U.N. report also linked past injustices to recent police killings
>   of black men that have sparked protests across the U.S.
>
> “Contemporary police killings and the trauma that they create are
>   reminiscent of the past racial terror of lynching,” the report said.
>
> The U.S. created a reparations plan in the immediate [aftermath of the
>   Civil War](http://www.pbs.org/wnet/african-americans-many-rivers-to-cross/history/the-truth-behind-40-acres-and-a-mule/) that stated that freed families would be granted “forty
>   acres of tillable land” and a mule from the Union Army. The plan,
>   proposed by Union General William T. Sherman after meetings with black
>   community leaders in Savannah, Georgia, was reversed by President
>   Andrew Johnson and the land was returned to plantation owners.

> I'm not sure why this question gets downvoted with no stated
>   objections

That occurs more frequently than one might even imagine when the subject matter of the question deals with anything remotely related to independent Black political thought outside of the control of western academia. To be blunt, Stack Exchange endorses and even encourages institutional racism.

The role of [COINTELPRO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COINTELPRO) cannot be overstated in historical contexts where African-Americans formed their own governments no matter the politics of the black government; that is, whether the group advocated self-determination through non-violent means or not, see [Republic of New Afrika](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Republic_of_New_Afrika); [Black Liberation Army](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Liberation_Army); while African nations were simultaneously being attacked by other arms of the U.S. government, e.g., [Patrice Lumumba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patrice_Lumumba). That is, the U.S. generally assassinates, deports or imprisons any African-Americans who are not U.S. co-opted proxies that reach the international stage as independent representatives of any significant portion of the African-American population.

After being off of the international stage, and following roughly 50 to 100 years (e.g., Marcus Garvey; heavyweight champion of the world Jack Johnson), the U.S. might *resolve* that the original charges were trumped up; false; a pretext to get rid of a "black messiah", and even black owned bookstores [The FBI's War on Black-Owned Bookstores](https://www.theatlantic.com/politics/archive/2018/02/fbi-black-bookstores/553598/), see [COINTELPRO Long-Range Goals and Prevention of a Black "Messiah"](https://genius.com/Federal-bureau-of-investigation-cointelpro-long-range-goals-and-prevention-of-a-black-messiah-annotated)

> 2. Prevent the RISE OF A "MESSIAH" who could unify, and electrify, the militant black nationalist movement. Malcolm X might have been such a
>      "messiah;" he is the martyr of the movement today. Martin Luther King,
>      Stokely Carmichael and Elijah Muhammed all aspire to this position.
>      Elijah Muhammed is less of a threat because of his age. King could be
>      a very real contender for this position should he abandon his supposed
>      "obedience" to "white, liberal doctrines" (nonviolence) and embrace
>      black nationalism. Carmichael has the necessary charisma to be a real
>      threat in this way.

in detail see [FBI COINTELPRO-Black Extremism](https://archive.org/stream/FBI-COINTELPRO-BLACK/100-HQ-448006-01#page/n0).

```
107th CONGRESS
  1st Session
H. RES. 50

    Expressing the sense of Congress with respect to Marcus Garvey.


_______________________________________________________________________


                    IN THE HOUSE OF REPRESENTATIVES

                           February 14, 2001

 Mr. Rangel submitted the following resolution; which was referred to 
                     the Committee on the Judiciary

_______________________________________________________________________

                               RESOLUTION



    Expressing the sense of Congress with respect to Marcus Garvey.

Whereas Marcus Mosiah Garvey was born in St. Ann's Bay, Jamaica, on August 17, 
        1887, and emigrated to the United States where he founded the Universal 
        Negro Improvement Association;
Whereas Marcus Garvey was the father of the largest African-American movement 
        for human rights and economic self-sufficiency of all time, attracting 
        millions of followers in the United States, the Caribbean, Latin 
        America, Africa, and Europe;
Whereas Marcus Garvey's philosophy inspired some of the world's great Black 
        leaders;
Whereas leading a movement for economic independence among Black Americans, 
        Marcus Garvey became the target of surveillance and harassment by United 
        States Government law enforcement agencies;
Whereas Marcus Garvey was prosecuted and convicted of mail fraud, imprisoned, 
        and later, deported to Jamaica;
Whereas the case against Marcus Garvey was politically motivated, the charges 
        unsubstantiated, and his conviction unjust;
Whereas millions of petitioners have appealed for his exoneration;
Whereas Marcus Garvey is recognized as a national hero in his native Jamaica, 
        and as a towering figure in nations around the world; and
Whereas Marcus Garvey's life and contributions to the United States should be 
        recognized and appropriate steps taken to restore his name and 
        reputation in this country: Now, therefore, be it
    Resolved, That it is the sense of Congress that--
            (1) Marcus Garvey was innocent of the charges brought 
        against him by the United States Government;
            (2) Marcus Garvey is and should be recognized 
        internationally as a leader and thinker in the struggle for 
        human rights; and
            (3) the President should take appropriate measures to clear 
        Marcus Garvey's good name.
```

Thus, the African-American - African connections are largely informal and intimate, rather than formal and overt, due to the U.S. governments' policy of not permitting African-American independent self-determination - by means of assassination; deportation; imprisonment, etc.

To openly call for a black nation-state or communicate with an African states-person on the international stage is contrary to U.S. domestic and foreign policy; it requires a fair amount of awareness of the political arena and a modicum of intestinal fortitude and tenacity.

Comment: Well, I upvoted, because the first example (Libya) is something I didn't know about. The rest of your post although interesting, I'm not too sure how it relates to my question... The last half argues that COINTELPRO (which seems to have ended in the 70s) historically played a role in preventing closer contacts, and is a reason why we didn't see more examples.

Comment: @Fizz The question is rather broad. The term "brothers" in the title is a misnomer as well. Just because someone appears to be "black" does not mean that they did not or do not work for the policy makers behind COINTELPRO. Cannot speak for them, though it might be edifying to you to look into why the Nation of Gods and Earths, or 5% Nation, state that they are not "pro-black and not anti-white". Know several individuals who travel to Africa for different reasons; some help developing sustainable clean water for remote communities; others took the slogan "love or leave it" literally.

Comment: @Fizz Will try to dig up relevant links to the material mentioned at the previous comment. Yes, the last half is a very real consideration. It is not as if we do not have a historical record to prove what will more than likely occur. And there is no one to call when one is exposed politically and physically. Which is why so vigorously challenged to premise of there actually being a "black supremacist" organization which exists in the real world. What is their phone number? Will they come riding in on a black horse when the international stage is reached?

Comment: @Fizz Important: am not a member of the Nation of Gods and Earths, so cannot speak for them. Am citing their philosophy on why they are not "pro-black" or "anti-white" to illustrate the issue with the blanket statement of "brothers" at the title of the question [We Are NOT Anti White Nor Pro Black. We are Pro righteousness!!!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s8D47V4cO1k) and a "black" person who claimed to have actively worked for a certain agency against "black" people [MUST SEE! BLACK FBI SPY TELLS EVERYTHING](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_pCk1qc4JvI)

Comment: @Fizz There are so few examples _readily citable_ due to the policies of COINTELPRO. It is not something that people on either side of oceans generally print in newspapers due to the _policy_ of the U.S. which continue _after_ COINTELPRO; there is still a "Black Desk". Those black students who are _trained_ in international relations, are recruited by the State Department, et al. The very idea of a black nation brings to mind Tulsa https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/31735/21216 which is a palpable fear for some: you black people in the U.S. are not allowed to even think about your own state.